# Change table header color using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC5 application which uses bootstrap. The table column name is in black
on white background and I want to change it to a blue background and the column
name will be in white, how could I do that?
I tried to play with the CSS classes without success...

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />


    <table class="table" >
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox1)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your CSS

```
th {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David,where in the CSS?in the site.css file ? how should I refer to it in the code?

Comment: Add it to site.css, the template should already be referencing it so you won't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks you very much David,Voted UP! it works but I have some problem that when I click on add row and I append new row to the table It also have the same blue and white color,how can I avoid it?   This is the code which add the row on click...var html = '<tr><th>@Html.TextBox("Name")</th><th>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</th><th>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox2")</th><th>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox3")</th><th></th></tr>';

Answer (score 12):

You could simply apply one of the bootstrap [contextual background colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds) to the header row. In this case (blue background, white text): primary.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table" >
  <tr class="bg-primary">
    <th>
        Firstname
    </th>
    <th>
        Surname
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Roe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the lesser "hacky" approach as it uses no custom CSS but Boostrap's CSS classes. But it let you choose only from the known color classes `danger`, `info`, `success`, `primary` and `warning` which is maybe a bit limited. But maybe this is not the right CSS class at all? Just a 2nd thought!

Comment: There are also ´table-*` color classes. (BS 4.0.0)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to separate your table header and table body:

```
thead th {
    background-color: #006DCC;
    color: white;
}

tbody td {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Have a look at this example for separation of head and body of table. [JsFiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/zaEFz/184/)

Answer (score 1):

```
//use css
.blue {
    background-color:blue !important;
}
.blue th {
    color:white !important;
}

//html
<table class="table blue">.....</table>
```

Comment: This will make the whole table background blue and  not change the text colour as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
table.table tr th{background-color:blue !important; font-color:white !important;}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks but where should I put it?

Comment: you have one style.css or any css file which you are using you can write in bottom of it..

Comment: There is no such css property as font-color

Comment: Also, use of !important should be avoided at all costs and only used as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

there's a bootstrap function to change the color of table header called **thead-dark** for dark background of table header and **thead-light** for light background of table header. Your code will look like this after using this function.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="thead-danger">
        <!-- here I used dark table headre -->
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox1)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't set color to **tr** or **thead** tag . you should change color of **th** tag with style or :

````
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: red; /* Choose your own color here */
}```
````