# Different striping for table heading with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap guide has info on how to add [striped rows](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-striped) to a table. But in the examples given, the heading row (which contains "#", "First Name",...) has the same striping as row 2 ("2", "Jacob", ...).

Is there a "Bootstrap way" of changing the striping of the heading row, as opposed to specifying in CSS the background color of a `<th>` element?

Changing the order of striping, such that the heading row started grey, and example #2 was grey, but where the heading row and example #2 used the same shade of grey, wouldn't solve the problem. The heading row is special, so it should have its own special background shade.

Comment: Uhm... you change the background property of the `<th>` element, that's about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change table header color using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928526/change-table-header-color-using-bootstrap)

Comment: @TinyGiant Isn't he asking for a different way? "as opposed to specifying in CSS"

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Do you want to "inverse" the colors of the striping? Starting from grey in the heading then white in the first row, etc.?

Comment: I don't know if it is a "Boostrap way", but you could erase the `<thead>` and just add a table row `<tr style="font-weight:bold">` with your header. That way your header would have the grey striping, if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: @tomasyany Yeah he's asking if there is any method, other than the currently accepted correct method, that is specifically endorsed by Twitter-Bootstrap. The answer (AFAIK) is no, use the currently accepted correct method. I have been wrong at least once though.

Comment: @tomasyany thanks for asking, but swapping the colors of the striping isn't what I'm after - see the edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap helper classes to add a deferent shade of color like this

```
<thead class="bg-success"></thead>
```

[image: Bootstrap Striped table]

but colors are limited 5 more color are available other then white and grey. you can find them [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds).